# 'segue' to same view controller from different table view cells

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a tableview with five cells.

I would like each cell to segue to the same view controller, changing a property in the view controller depending on which cell was selected (didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

The main trick is that I'd like to use a storyboarded view controller for the segued to view controller.

Gratzi!

Answer (score 1):

connect the view or tableview and next view controller directly by segue , but not tableview cell .
And then ,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //set any value depending on which cell was selected
     //...
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:self];
}
```

about changing a property :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    MyViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    [viewController setAnyValue:anyvalue];
}
```

Comment: How do I connect the view or tableview (and which one?) to the next view controller?  I tried control-dragging but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you define segue identifier in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to connect to anything but a tableviewcell. I have two sections in the tableview - section one (with 5 cells) goes to one view controller - section two (with one cell) goes to another.